# git's analog of "hg pull"

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

In mercurial when I run `hg pull` I will get all of changes from the remote repository but this command  won't update the local working dir. When I run `hg update` this command will apply the changes in the working dir.

In git when I run `git pull` the command will get and apply the changes in the working dir.

So my question is how to pull the changes (in git) from the remote repository but not applying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the command you are seeking is `git fetch`.  From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their histories. Remote-tracking branches are updated.

Git fetch loads all the changes from the remote without updating your actual local branches.  In the blurb above, "remote-tracking" branches are local branches (yes, it's confusing) which track the state in the remote repository, but they are not your local branches.

Assuming you are on branch `master`, then:

```
git fetch origin          # updates origin/master
git merge origin/master   # updates your local master
```

Doing `git pull origin master` is equivalent to doing `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

Comment: Thanks but how do I apply the changes in the working dir after git fetch?